# Loading a django project on my home computer

Tags: python, django

Bear with me as I'm still pretty new to Python and Django

I copied a project I'm working on from my universities PCs to USB, and when I load it onto my laptop and try to run it using this code in the cmd: `python manage.py runserver`

I got this error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x01D4EB70>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 270, in validate
    raise CommandError("One or more models did not validate:\n%s" % error_text)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
groupcraft.userprofile: "picture": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong or what I'm not doing?

Answer (score 3):

> One or more models did not validate: groupcraft.userprofile: "picture": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

You're using Django's `ImageField` in one of your models, with relies on PIL. You can [download and install a Windows installer for PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (make sure you select the correct file based on your Python version).

Comment: Installing PIL on a windows machine doesn't use PIP, it has to use an MSI file because WinSxS sucks.

Answer (score 1):

for the newest PIL version, just type:

```
easy_install http://effbot.org/downloads/PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe
```

You should always check for "requirements.txt" file inside of the existing project, to make sure you have all the python libraries included.

When working on windows, you need to make sure to install binary version of some of those libs.